# How to find doubling in a word?

Tags: python-3.x

My task is to check the word list on doublings and output the result in a dictionary.

Firstly i was trying to execute this code:

```
for word in wordsList:
    for letter in word:
        if word[letter] == word[letter+1]:
```

But as long as i got a mistake, i've changed it a bit:

```
wordsList = ["creativity", "anna", "civic", "apology", "refer", "mistress", "rotor", "mindset"]
dictionary = {}

for word in wordsList:
    for letter in range(len(word)-1):
        if word[letter] == word[letter+1]:
            dictionary[word] = ("This word has a doubling")
        else:
            dictionary[word] = ("This word has no doubling")
print(dictionary)
```

Now it works, but not properly. I really need suggestions! Thanks in advance

I expect the output
{creativity: 'This word has no doubling'}, {anna: 'This ward has a doubling'} etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wordsList = ["creativity", "anna", "civic", "apology", "refer", "mistress", "rotor", "mindset"]
dictionary = {}

for word in wordsList:
    for index, char in enumerate(word[:-1]):    # Take one less to prevent out of bounds
        if word[index + 1] == char:             # Check char with next char
            dictionary[word] = True
            break                               # The one you forgot, with the break you wouldnt override the state
    else:
        dictionary[word] = False

print(dictionary)
```

You forgot the break statement; The loop would continue and override your found conclusion.
I made my own implementation of your casus.

Comment: Thanks so much, that really works as i need! Would you be so kind to  explain what this line "enumerate(word[:-1])" does, coz im new to python and don't quite understand, thanks again!

Comment: The enumerate will index your list to a list of tuples (iirc), So ['item_1', 'item_2'] becomes [(0, 'item_1'), (1, 'item_2')]. Therefor when we loop over it with the for loop we get the index and item (char in your case).

[:-1] will take your list of characters (also known as a word :]) and split it to -1 character. So "test"[:-1] would give "tes" and "test"[:-2] gives "te"

Comment: So basically the tuple contains an index and a string?

Comment: Correct; enumerate adds the index

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Comment: I'm very sorry to bother you again. If you have time, answer please. I was in a hurry saying i got it, hence i'm not.
For example, word "anna":
i got how the [index + 1] == char works, so we basically numerate a - 0, n - 1, and by adding 1 we calculate if the next letter is the same. but why we should use word[:-1] to remove the last letter from the word?

Comment: Because we can't compare the last character with a non existent beyond last character.

Answer (score 0):

```py
wordsList = ["creativity", "anna", "civic", "apology", "refer", "mistress", "rotor", "mindset"]
dictionaries = []
for word in wordsList: #for example:creativity
    alphabets=[]
    for x in word:
        alphabets+=x #now alphabets==['c','r','e','a','t','i','v','i','t','y']
    num=0
    while True:
        x=alphabets[0]  #for example 'c'
        alphabets.remove(x)  #now alphabets==['r','e','a','t','i','v','i','t','y']
        if x in alphabets:  # if alphabets contain 'c'
            doubling=True   # it is doubling
            break                
        else:
            doubling=False  #continue checking
            if len(alphabets)==1:  #if there is only one left
                break              #there is no doubling
    if doubling:
        dictionaries.append({word:"This word has a doubling"})
    else:
        dictionaries.append({word:"This word has no doubling"})
print(dictionaries)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! However, when i run it, all words have doubling

Comment: I don't really good at english , I think your doubling means two same alphabets in a word sorry

Comment: If by 'alphabets' you mean 'letters' (a,b,c), and doubling is aa, bb, cc in a word. The output is this: [{'creativity': 'This word has a doubling'}, {'anna': 'This word has a doubling'}, {'civic': 'This word has a doubling'}, {'apology': 'This word has a doubling'}, {'refer': 'This word has a doubling'}, {'mistress': 'This word has a doubling'}. So all words have doubling!

Comment: I know but I'm not good at english cuz I'm not English people

Comment: No probs mate, your code was quite interesting, it was very helpful for my other task! Cheers!